# Angular LoadAsh - filtering records matching by fields on Multiple Objects of different Type

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been struggling a bit learning loadash and how to correctly pull the data I want with some more advanced tricks.  Single objects and lookups are pretty simple but i'm trying to pull all array records by a groupId, if that groupId exists in another object that isn't the same.

For example:
    Generic JSON example of objects, each are arrays of records.

```
Groups .. 
{
    groupId:
    name:
    code:
}

Options ..
{
    groupId:
    optionId:
    name:
    code:
}
```

The problem I'm having is pulling all Options only if that groupId exist in the Groups array in loadash.

I've tried some stuff like

```
var results = [];
_.forEach(Groups, function(g) {
    var found _.find(Options, g, function(option, group) {
         return option.groupId === group.groupId;
    })
    results.push(found);
});
```

I haven't had much luck figuring out the best way to filter these down.

Any words if wisdom would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work,

```
var result = _.filter(Options, function(o) { 
  return _.filter(Groups, function(g) { return g.groupId == o.groupid; }).length > 0;
});
```

actually i think the inner search would perform better with `find`, since it returns the first match, not sure though

```
var result = _.filter(Options, function(o) { 
  return _.find(Groups, { 'groupId': o.groupid });
});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, i knew i was missing something simple.  Thank you!